# Where to view the program counter (PC) and instruction register (IR) in gdb

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, instruction-set

Is it possible to view the current program counter and instruction register in gdb? Here is the output of a basic C program (add an int and return it) in gdb on ubuntu14:

[image]

I thought I'd see something like `pc` or `ir` but perhaps it's either stored as something else or not shown at all in the register. Where would I see that?

Comment: RIP = 64-bit instruction pointer.

Comment: There is no architectural IR that a debugger could view on most (or any) ISAs, and definitely not x86.  [x86 registers: MBR/MDR and instruction registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51522368).  Use `disas $pc` to see the instruction pointed-to by the program counter (RIP in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In x86 64bit, which seems like what you are dealing with from the picture, the program counter is `rip` (and `eip` for 32bit). There's no Instruction Register in x86.

In GDB you can refer to the program counter as `$pc` (generic CPU-agnostic name) or `$rip` (x86-64 specific name).

Comment: out of curiosity, why is there no Instruction Register in x86? I'm obviously very new to asm and just trying to learn it a bit so have only played around with very basic models. How does the instruction get decoded in the Fetch cycle then?

Comment: @David542 design choice. You can find a longer answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522980/3889449).