# Behavior of bus address in "popl %eax"

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, bus

In a scenario where I have the following assembly instruction:

```
popl %eax
```

Would there be any information flowing through the address bus?

From what I understand about the functionality of a CPU, there would be no information flowing through it, since it would only be storing the value of %esp into %eax, therefore using only the CPU bus. Nevertheless, I think I am wrong. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: `pop` does not transfer `esp` into `eax`. It reads from memory at address `esp`.

Comment: Ooh, okay, so it would have to look for what is inside esp address, wouldn't it?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you, Jester!

Comment: Note that depending on whether the CPU has caches or not, no access to external RAM may actually happen.  Refer to the instruction set reference for the behaviour of instructions.

Comment: Real x86 CPUs are not simple.  [x86 registers: MBR/MDR and instruction registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51522368).  A 386 without a data cache might put the address of every load on an actual external bus, but modern CPUs work in cache lines.