# Is it possible to implement pipelining in a accumulator based machine/ISA?

Tags: assembly, pipeline, cpu-architecture, accumulator

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but here it goes:

I was wondering if it is possible to implement pipelining stages into a Von-Neuman Architecture that uses an accumulator to hold a value along with a PC, memory buffer register, instruction register, and memory address register? There would also be a output register to hold the output and a input register to hold input.

I was wondering this and was thinking that a 3-stage pipeline(Fetch,Decode,Execute) would be more feasible than a 5-stage pipeline as that would introduce the need of extra registers.

Are there any examples of this and is it possible to implement theoretically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, of course, at least pipelining fetch/decode, and probably data-load would be extra helpful since every instruction will have a data memory address embedded in it.

(Some instructions might allow a memory-indirect addressing mode, i.e. load a pointer from memory and then dereference it, allowing indirect addressing without self-modifying code.  An in-order pipeline would probably have to stall while doing the 2nd load.  Self-modifying code sucks a lot for pipelining and especially OoO exec, if you want to keep the pipeline coherent.  You could keep it simple and only guarantee coherence after a jump or something, and discard fetch/decode results on jumps to make sure you're observing newly-stored instructions, if you want to support self-modifying code like some toy accumulator ISAs need to e.g. loop over an array.  (e.g. [Little Man Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer)) )

Register-renaming with out-of-order execution would probably be valuable, given that software has only 1 architectural register to play with.  A store buffer with store forwarding would provide the equivalent for memory / cache, given effective memory disambiguation (store-forwarding detection).  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) for more about what store buffers do, and links from there including https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/.

**Note that modern x86 CPUs are able to pipeline instructions like `add eax, [mem]` memory-source add into the accumulator**, and `mov [mem], eax` stores of the accumulator.  (x86 has other registers, but you could in theory use it with just the one).  Modern x86 CPUs decode memory-source ALU instructions to 2 uops, the load and the add, which execute separately in the out-of-order back-end.  See [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)
 for a gentle intro that builds up to more complex CPUs, including modern x86 decoding to "RISC-like" micro-ops.

**You could build a pipeline pretty much exactly like Intel Sandybridge-family** (see David Kanter's deep dive with block diagrams of different parts of the front and back ends in Haswell - https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/) or AMD Zen, that runs an accumulator ISA instead of x86.

Or to keep it a bit simpler, like P5 Pentium (dual issue in-order without decoding to RISC-like uops, so it can't pipeline memory-source ALU instructions as well), or 486 (in-order pipelined single issue).

---

**I doubt there are any commercial examples**; AFAIK no pure accumulator ISAs are relevant enough that anyone would want to buy a high-performance implementation of an inherently inefficient ISA, instead of buying a CPU that could run a register ISA faster for the same cost in dollars, power, silicon, and design effort.

(i.e. you *could* do this, or you could spend similar effort to pipeline a good ISA like ARM, MIPS, or RISC-V.  Or even something more CISCish like m68k.)

---

No reason to assume a toy microarchitecture with a single MAR/MBR/IR, though.  Each instruction needs its own IR through the pipeline, assuming it's an ISA with fixed-width instructions that even makes sense to have an IR, rather than control signals based on decode results.

[x86 registers: MBR/MDR and instruction registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522368/x86-registers-mbr-mdr-and-instruction-registers) explains why real-world x86 CPUs don't have just one of those, and don't have an "IR" at all.  And that a MAR/MBR is too simple a model for pipelined cache access, especially on a CPU with virtual memory.

Comment: Also related: https://www.realworldtech.com/architecture-basics/2/ for a taxonomy of accumulator vs. stack vs. register machines.